# Nodejs express Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, express

I have images in array and I am updating in database. But issue its showing this error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'
```

And this is my code

```
const updateCompany = async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.files;
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request');
    const companyLogoName = file[0].filename;
    const companyImageName = file[1].filename;

    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    // console.log(`${basePath}${companyLogoName}`);
    // console.log(`${basePath}${companyImageName}`);

    try {
        const updateCompany = Company.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            companyName: req.body.companyName,
            companyDescription: req.body.companyDescription,
            companyWebsite: req.body.companyWebsite,
            companyDHeadQuater: req.body.companyDHeadQuater,
            companySpecialities: req.body.companySpecialities,
            companyFounded: req.body.companyFounded,
            companyIndustry: req.body.companyIndustry,
            companyMinEmploye: req.body.companyMinEmploye,
            companyMaxEmploye: req.body.companyMaxEmploye,
            companyType: req.body.companyType,
            companyLogo: `${basePath}${companyLogoName}`,
            companyImage: `${basePath}${companyImageName}`,

        }, {
            new: true
        });
        // console.log(updateCompany);

        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: updateCompany })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            console.error(Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message))
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message)[0] })
        }
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err })
    }
};
```

In console its showing correct path of images means multer file etc is working but issue is on update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing any callback function to `findByIdAndUpdate`, neither are you using `await`. According to the mongoose doc, `findByIdAndUpdate` will return an instance of `Query` object if no callback is passed. So `updateCompany` is actual an instance of `Query` object which express is trying to render as json and that's why the error at this line:

> return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: updateCompany })

You could either use `await` or add a callback function as specified in the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate).